# How can I separate Every Number image from this Snake Ladder?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-sprite

How to Separate Every number into images from This Snake Ladder Using Photoshop
Like in this photo, number 1 box image, number 2 box image... and so on upto 100
 
[image]

Comment: do you really mean "every number" or do you mean "every square which has a number"

Comment: Can't you just draw a box and type a number in the center of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the slice tool! Mini explanation bellow (CS6).

[image]